# Issue with basic Angular5 setup

Tags: angular, npm, angular-cli

I can't get Angular5 to basically setup and run.

In my home directory,

```
$ sudo npm install @angular/cli -g

$ ng new my-verbsandvocab

$ cd my-verbsandvocab

$ ng serve
```

This gives me the error message,

```
Please make sure your package.json contains both @angular/compiler-cli and typescript in
devDependencies, then delete node_modules and package-lock.json (if you have one) and
run npm install again.
```

npm 3.10.10

tsc Version 2.6.2

package.json

```
{ ......
      "dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
        "core-js": "^2.4.1",
        "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
        "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@angular/cli": "1.6.3",
        "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
        "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
        "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
        "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
        "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
        "codelyzer": "^4.0.1",
        "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
        "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
        "karma": "~1.7.0",
        "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
        "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
        "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
        "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
        "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
        "protractor": "~5.1.2",
        "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
        "tslint": "~5.7.0",
        "typescript": "~2.4.2"
      }
    }
```

I can't see anything wrong with this setup. I have recently been playing with typescript and installed. Could that effect the installation of Angular?

**SOLUTION**

```
$ sudo npm install
```

Running npm install as superuser did the trick

Comment: Did you run npm install ? I know the CLI download required packages, but I'm not sure if it runs npm install to install your own dependencies

Comment: I’d remove typescript globally if you have that installed and see if that changes things.

Comment: @trichetriche thanks I did run npm install and have re-run it since But still the same error message

Comment: @Tamas thanks for the suggestion, I uninstalled typescript as you mentioned and then ran npm install but still the same error

Comment: It worked when I ran sudo npm install but not sure if the uninstalling of typescript was also necessary or not, but I suppose it is better to run package locally in directories.

Comment: Strange behavior indeed ... Did you install npm (or node) with a sudo command ? If so, you need to change the rights on npm so that you can run it without sudo

Comment: Possibly and probably but I'm not sure.

Comment: Have a Look at this [Angular Tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeU20i-yc6o), it helped me to create my first Application

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$ sudo npm install

Running npm install as superuser did the trick

Answer (score 0):

```
$ sudo npm install @angular/cli -g
```

command works fine but not for the first time, you have to get the latest cli for that use command

```
$ sudo npm install --save-dev @angular/cli@latest
```

then it will work fine.
For more details have a look at this [[Angular Video]](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EeU20i-yc6o), this helps me to create my first angular 5 app.

Comment: --save is to also include it in the package.json file